# Selecionar os dados mais repetidos em uma coluna e exibi-los

Tags: php, sql

Boa noite, estou em um projeto no qual devo fazer um site que dê para os usuários recomendarem filmes, e depois mostrar os mais recomendados.

Eu já fiz o sistema de recomendar, agora preciso fazer a lista de mais recomendados.

O sistema funciona assim:

O usuário recomenda um filme e esse dado vai para uma coluna de uma tabela, quero fazer com que o sistema conte os dados mais repetidos dessa coluna e me mostre o 10 mais repetidos.Tenho duas dúvidas.

1.Como fazer o sql contar e organizar os mais repetidos.

2.Como fazer um "ECHO" para as rows da tabela?

Agradeço desde já :)

ATUALIZAÇÂO!!!

Apesar de eu seguir o código que você me falou, aparece erros no resultado do código, como esse:

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/u313079178/public_html/index.php on line 62
Não foi possível realizar a busca
Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/u313079178/public_html/index.php on line 66

O meu código está assim :

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT filme, COUNT(filme) FROM dados_rec
      GROUP BY filme
      ORDER BY COUNT(filme) DESC LIMIT 10");
```

if(!$result) {
    echo "Não foi possível realizar a busca";
}
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi seu problema, pra isso você terá que usar as funções "count", "group by" e "order by" do sql, e de preferência uma função que limite o número de linhas retornadas na query, mas isso depende de qual banco vc está usando.

Primeiro você vai usar o group by pra agrupar os dados que se repetem em uma coluna:

```
select filme from recomendacao group by filme
```

Depois você vai contar os filmes que se repetem:

```
select filme, count(filme) from recomendacao group by filme
```

Por ultimo vc vai ordenar de froma descendente (do maior para o menor) pelo numero de filmes contados em cada grupo:

```
select filme, count(filme) from recomendacao group by filme order by count(filme) desc
```

para limitar aos 10 primeiros, depende de cada banco, se for o mysql (ou mariadb) vc vai procurar pela função "limit".

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, eu sabia sobre esse count mas eu não sabia usar e nem organizar os rows, valeu.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, apareceram alguns erros inesperados, tem como me ajudar?

Comment: Você tem q passar a conexão como primeiro argumento da função mysqli_query. assim: 

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);